# SQL - How to show in one row the same field with different values from 2 rows

Tags: sql, case, union

I have a select with a specific 'where' clause where I get 2 rows, but I will need to show in one row these 2 values but with different 'names'

```
select 
case when t_docn <> 0 then t_docd end as doc_date,
case when t_docn = 0 then t_docd end as pay_date
from
ttfacr200606

where
t_ninv = '40000122'
and
t_ccur = 'BRL'
```

with this code I am getting

```
doc_date    pay_date
NULL    2015-08-21 00:00:00.000
2015-09-18 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

I will need

```
doc_date    pay_date
2015-09-18 00:00:00.000 2015-08-21 00:00:00.000
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: What is the field that defines the point of commonality between the records? It woudl pay to include the actual data as well as the result of your query

Comment: you can use `Outer Apply` to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregation function to do that, although you will need to verify if it will fit for all cases you have. It will be like this:

```
select 
       t_ninv, 
       max(case when t_docn <> 0 then t_docd else null end) as doc_date,
       max(case when t_docn = 0 then t_docd else null end) as pay_date
  from ttfacr200606
 where t_ccur = 'BRL'
   and t_ninv = '40000122'
 group by t_ninv;
```

Pay attention that I used a column to be the common point as said in comments, because if you wont use it and with many rows the query result can be unpredictable.

Comment: Hello Jorge, thank you for your tip but when I am executing your code, its saying: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'max' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: sql server 11.0.2100 its from our ERP DB, I am working in a report

Comment: OOOhhhh sorry it is in fact wrong, I copied your query and forgot to remove the alias

Comment: Try it now, please.

Comment: omg man..it worked..thanks! Its my first time asking questions on stack overflow..for some time I only used a research database, thanks btw! I will pay attention on this tips...my question was for a very specific case, but my report is larger, so I will try now to see how it goes with a large amount of data. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Great. Make sure to accept the answer if it really helped you. You do that by clicking on the V icon in the left side of the answer (I think you can do it after 15 minutes or so). And keep coming this is the right place to learn